# ALTER TABLE CHANGE não está renomeando as constraints automaticamente no servidor de produção

Tags: mariadb

Segundo a documentação do MySQL (que nesse caso, acredito eu, também se aplica ao MariaDB), quando o comando `CHANGE` é utilizado para renomear uma coluna, as constraints são automaticamente renomeadas também:

[image: Documentação]

Fazendo um teste local, eu renomeei uma coluna, que é chave estrangeira, e **o comando rodou normalmente**, inclusive **renomeando a constraint** para o novo nome:

```
ALTER TABLE customers_groups CHANGE cliente_id customer_id INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
```

Porém, ao rodar o mesmo comando no servidor (uma instância MariaDB na AWS RDS), o seguinte erro é apresentado:

```
Cannot drop index 'clientes_grupos_cliente_id_foreign': needed in a foreign key constraint
```

Sei que eu poderia dar um `DROP` e recriar as constraints, mas gostaria de saber o porquê de não estar renomeando automaticamente apenas com o `CHANGE` e apenas em produção.

Comment: só para confirmar, tem certeza que localmente tem exatamente a mesma estrutura que tem em produção, incluindo constraints e indexes?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Tenho sim. Talvez seja relevante informar, o sistema foi desenvolvido utilizando o framework Laravel. Então os dois ambientes tiveram as tabelas criadas pelas migrations. E o erro em questão acontece quando eu executo o método `$table->renameColumn('cliente_id', 'customer_id')`, mas no fim a instrução gerada é aquela mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso o seu problema não é com o MySQL, nem com o Maria DB. E sim com o Lavarel.
Alguns comandos de alto nível quando utilizados, na verdade implementam ações básicas para nós ao invés de termos que faze-lo. Isso serve tanto para querys em todos os Dbs, quanto para frameworks e as próprias linguagens de programação. No seu caso quando utiliza o comando CHANGE column no DB, por debaixo dos panos ele implementa um drop e um create. Salvando a tabela(e/ou os dados contidos na coluna, juntamente com um identificador, em uma arvore, temporariamente em memoria. Após isso ele executa o drop da coluna, o create da coluna nova e insere os dados da tabela temporária na nova coluna de acordo com seu dado correspondente). Utilizando Lavarel temos uma proteção para evitar perda de dados em ambientes de prodção ao executar operações destrutivas. Dependendo da configuração e do tamanho da coluna, do servidor, etc. pode encontrar essa limitação também no DB. Para executar esse tipo de operação em produção e diminuir os riscos o melhor e criar novas tabelas, e rodar o dump para as novas renomeandos-as posteriormente. Caso queira rodar o comando mesmo assim rode diretamente no DB. Para rodar pelo lavarel, terá de criar uma migration e aplicar --force, contudo não tenho total certeza de que funcionará pois nunca o fiz, você poderá ter que executar as ações uma a uma. Segue passagem da doc do lavarel sobre operações destrutivas :

Forçando Migrations Para Rodar em Produção
Algumas operações de migration são destrutivas, que significa que eles podem causar a perda de dados. A fim de protegê-lo de executar esses comandos no banco de dados em produção, você será solicitado para confirmação antes desses comandos serem executados. Para forçar os comandos e executar sem um prompt, use o sinalizador --force:

php artisan migrate --force

** Um outro ponto é confirmar que todas as dependências do ambiente de produção estão iguais as do ambiente de desenvolvimento.

link da doc : https://github.com/artesaos/laravel-docs/blob/master/pt_BR/migrations.md

Comment: Conseguiu resolver ?

Answer (score 0):

No Postgres eu usaria um CASCADE, pois o que está impedindo não é a tabela que está sendo renomeada, mas sim as que a usam como dependência.

Eu não tenho um ambiente Mysql aqui, mas você poderia testar com um 'ON UPDATE CASCADE'.